# Firebase Authentication email-already-in-use error?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I read this section of the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#getredirectresult

and I can't see the difference between these two errors:

`auth/account-exists-with-different-credential`
and
`auth/email-already-in-use`

The former says

> Thrown if there already exists an account with the email address asserted by the credential

And the latter says

> Thrown if the email corresponding to the credential already exists among your users

This and the rest of the paragraphs say the same thing to me, with different words. Any comments on this would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

From what I see in my tests, I would now say that:

- `auth/account-exists-with-different-credential`: happens when the user **signs in with a provider credential** which is not yet linked to one of our accounts, but which references an email address which is used by one of our accounts
- `auth/email-already-in-use`: happens when trying to **link a provider credential** which is not yet linked to one of our accounts, but which references an email address which is used by one of our accounts

  So basically they are the same thing so far, but happen after different events. In this case, maybe `auth/account-exists-with-different-credential` should have been used instead, I'll email the Firebase support about this.

  But `auth/email-already-in-use` also happens when trying to **link an email credential** while the email is already used by one of our accounts. In which case it does make sense.